# Find matched composite data and replace using macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a scenario where I have to look up two columns in worksheet1 and search for match in worksheet2, if any matching column found then replace the value.

[image: Workshhet1]

[image: Worksheet2]

Currently I have fixed out to find a match in one column. Here is my code

```
 Sub FindMatch()
      Dim x As String
      Dim found As Boolean
      ' Select first line of data.
      Range("A2").Select
      ' Set search variable value.
      x = "A"
      ' Set Boolean variable "found" to false.
      found = False
      ' Set Do loop to stop at empty cell.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         ' Check active cell for search value.
         If ActiveCell.value = x Then
            found = True
            Exit Do
         End If
         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
   ' Check for found.
      If found = True Then
         MsgBox "Value found in cell " & ActiveCell.Address
      Else
         MsgBox "Value not found"
      End If
   End Sub
```

I want to search column "A" and "D" in worksheet 1 against column "A" & "B" in worksheet 2 
I searched in SO but didn't see any post similar to my requirement. Can anyone help me out.

Thanks !

Comment: So.. you are trying to compare which value with which value? Did you try anything and it didn't work? Maybe show an example of the desired result.

Comment: Use Match, it's a formula, then wrap an IsError around it, let the IsError be no match IsError .

Comment: sorry I dont have much reputation to upload more than 2 image links. I have updated my question with some code snippet.  @Miguel_Ryu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
 Sub FindMatch()

    Dim WS_one As Worksheet
    Dim WS_two As Worksheet

    Set WS_one = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set WS_two = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' Set worksheets to be used.

    Set lastCell = WS_one.Range("A:A").Find _
        ("*", after:=Cells(1, 1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    'set lastCell as last cell with any value
    For x = 1 To lastCell.Row
    'Set For loop to run until last cell with value.

        With WS_one
            'with sheet one only
            .Select
            Col_ValueA = .Cells(x, 1).Value
            Col_ValueD = .Cells(x, 4).Value
            'define value to search for
        End With

        With WS_two
            'with sheet two only
            .Select

            Set findvalue = .Range("A:A").Find _
                (Col_ValueA, after:=Cells(1, 1))
            'find 1st value equal to column A value

            Do
            'Do while no match found, and still values to check

                If Not findvalue Is Nothing Then
                    'if value exist then check for match

                    If .Cells(findvalue.Row, 2).Value = Col_ValueD Then
                        'check double match
                        ReplaceValue = .Cells(findvalue.Row, 3).Value
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        'if second value doesn't match find new Column A value
                        temp = findvalue.Row
                        'security check

                        Set findvalue = .Range("A:A").Find _
                            (Col_ValueA, after:=Cells(temp, 1))
                        'find new row

                        If temp = findvalue.Row Then
                        'if row doesnt change exit do
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    'if no column A match found exit do
                    Exit Do
                End If

            Loop
        End With

        If Not ReplaceValue = "" Then
            ' replacement exists paste in column E and reset replacement value
            WS_one.Cells(x, 5).Value = ReplaceValue
            ReplaceValue = ""
        End If
   Next
   WS_one.Select

End Sub
```

Essentially the code matches column A of sheet one with sheet two and if that value matches we check the second value. By the way, you might notice that the code I posted doesn't have select range and Active Cell anymore, try not to use those to often as the are not very secure and tend to make the code slower.